# Bracket finding algorithm lua?

Tags: algorithm, lua

I'm making a JSON parser and I am looking for an algorithm that can find all of the matching brackets (`[]`) and braces (`{}`) and put them into a table with the positions of the pair.

Examples of returned values:

```
table[x][firstPos][secondPos] = type

table[x] = {firstPos, secondPos, bracketType}
```

EDIT: Let `parse()` be the function that returns the bracket pairs. Let `table` be the value returned by the `parse()` function. Let `codeString` be the string containing the brackets that I want to detect. Let `firstPos` be the position of the first bracket in the `N`th pair of brackets. Let `secondPos` be the position of the second bracket in the `N`th pair of brackets. Let `bracketType` be the type of the bracket pair ("bracket" or "brace").

Example:

If you called:

```
table = parse(codeString)
```

`table[N][firstPos][secondPos]` would be equal to `type`.

Comment: See [how I did it](https://github.com/H2CO3/libjsonz/blob/master/src/jsonz.c). You almost surely want to use recursion.

Comment: @H2CO3 I don't know C, I'm looking for a way to do it in Lua.

Comment: The algorithm doesn't depend on the language.

Comment: Check out [LPeg](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my own algorithm.

```
function string:findAll(query)
    local firstSub = 1
    local lastSub = #query
    local result = {}
    while lastSub <= #self do
        if self:sub(firstSub, lastSub) == query then
            result[#result + 1] = firstSub
        end
        firstSub = firstSub + 1
        lastSub = lastSub + 1
    end
    return result
end

function string:findPair(openPos, openChar, closeChar)
    local counter = 1
    local closePos = openPos
    while closePos <= #self do
        closePos = closePos + 1
        if self:sub(closePos, closePos) == openChar then
            counter = counter + 1
        elseif self:sub(closePos, closePos) == closeChar then
            counter = counter - 1
        end
        if counter == 0 then
            return closePos
        end
    end
    return -1
end

function string:findBrackets(bracketType)
    local openBracket = ""
    local closeBracket = ""
    local openBrackets = {}
    local result = {}
    if bracketType == "[]" then
        openBracket = "["
        closeBracket = "]"
    elseif bracketType == "{}" then
        openBracket = "{"
        closeBracket = "}"
    elseif bracketType == "()" then
        openBracket = "("
        closeBracket = ")"
    elseif bracketType == "<>" then
        openBracket = "<"
        closeBracket = ">"
    else
        error("IllegalArgumentException: Invalid or unrecognized bracket type "..bracketType.."\nFunction: findBrackets()")
    end
    local openBrackets = self:findAll(openBracket)
    if not openBrackets[1] then
        return {}
    end
    for i, j in pairs(openBrackets) do
        result[#result + 1] = {j, self:findPair(j, openBracket, closeBracket)}
    end
    return result
end
```

Will output:

```
5   14
6   13
7   12
8   11
9   10
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, In plain Lua, you could do something like this, also taking into account nested brackets:

```
function bm(s)
    local res ={}
    if not s:match('%[') then
            return s
    end
    for k in s:gmatch('%b[]') do
            res[#res+1] = bm(k:sub(2,-2))
    end
    return res
end
```

Of course you can generalize this easy enough to braces, parentheses, whatever (do keep in mind the necessary escaping of [] in patterns , except behind the %b pattern).

If you're not restricted to plain Lua, you could use LPeg for more flexibility

If you are not looking for the contents of the brackets, but the locations, the recursive approach is harder to implement, since you should keep track of where you are. Easier is just walking through the string and match them while going:

```
function bm(s,i)
    local res={}
    res.par=res      -- Root
    local lev = 0
    for loc=1,#s do
        if s:sub(loc,loc) == '[' then
            lev = lev+1
            local t={par=res,start=loc,lev=lev}   -- keep track of the parent
            res[#res+1] = t                       -- Add to the parent
            res = t                               -- make this the current working table
            print('[',lev,loc)
        elseif s:sub(loc,loc) == ']' then
            lev = lev-1
            if lev<0 then error('too many ]') end -- more closing than opening.
            print(']',lev,loc)                  
            res.stop=loc                          -- save bracket closing position
            res = res.par                         -- revert to the parent.
        end
    end
    return res
end
```

Now that you have all matched brackets, you can loop through the table, extracting all locations.

Comment: Just return the **positions** of the brackets. If you do that, then I won't need to get the data within the brackets because I can just use the `sub()` function. This will provide more flexibility for me.

Comment: Well, changing this to return the positions of the brackets is easily don by placing empty captures `()` before and after the `%b[]` pattern. It'll need a bit of arithmetic for making the recursion work though.

Comment: It's a tad harder, but given this solution, you should be able to figure it out. That said, I'll see I have time this weekend.

Comment: On the live demo I get `input:22: 'end' expected (to close 'function' at line 1) near <eof>`. I put your new function with `print(unpack(bm("[hello[world]!]")))` for testing.

Comment: Good catch! there is indeed an end missing. Was ... Just corrected it

Comment: It would require a bit of fiddling, but I think I could get to be the way I want it. I'll comment back to you if I need any help.

Comment: I can almost get it to the way I want it. I can get the positions of all of the brackets, but I need a way to pair them up, which I can't figure out.

Comment: I wrote my own set of functions down below in the next answer.